# Http failure response for http://jinkins_Url/v/job/job_name/buildid/wfapi/: 0 Unknown Error in Angular 8 but status code is 200

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating one deployment dashboard of jenkins through angular 8. I am using http://Jenkinsmachine/job/job_name/build_id/wfapi/ API. when I am calling wfapi that it gives

> Http failure response for
>   http://Jenkinsmachine/job/job_name/build_id/wfapi/: 0 Unknown Error

but status code 200 ok.Please help me into it.

service.ts file:

```
export class EmployeeService {
  public apiUrl: string = "http://Jenkinsmachine/job/job_name/build_id/wfapi/";
  constructor( private http: HttpClient) { }
  getData(): Observable<jenkins[]>{
    return this.http.get<jenkins[]>(this.apiUrl,).catch(this.errorHandler);
   }
  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse)
  {  return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error");}
}
```

Comment: Do you see the response object in network requests?

Comment: yes.. i did not get any message in response